# Are there any good Uber-like taxi apps in Bulgaria?

Tags: taxis, bulgaria, mobile-apps

We'll travel from Sofia airport to Borovets, and we're trying to find some good way to find a taxi.

Comment: SOF airport has an organized taxi stand. Back in 2013 when I was there only one taxi operator was able to serve the airport, so I'm unsure you have many options there. Taxis were quite reasonably priced then; your ride to Botovets shouldn't cost more than $50 - and this is over an hour ride.

Comment: Uber itself may be there. We recently heard Uber is in Cairo Egypt for example. Maybe contacts Uber to ask.

Comment: Yeah, we took a taxi from the stand in the airport. Driver almost fall asleep during the ride.. but it's a different story.

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be at least two on Google Play:

1. [TaxiMe](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.taxime.client)
2. [maxim: order a taxi](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.taxsee.taxsee)

You can try to judge which one is more reliable based on the reviews of the app.